# How to find the coordinates of a Vertex from a VertexArray SFML

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, sfml

I'm using a VertexArray with Quads to make a TileMap for a little test. I'm trying to find out how to find out what vertex(quad) the gameobject is on.

```
bool load(const std::string& tileset, sf::Vector2u tileSize, const int* tiles, unsigned int width, unsigned int height)
{

    // load the tileset texture
    if (!m_tileset.loadFromFile(tileset))
        return false;

    // resize the vertex array to fit the level size
    m_vertices.setPrimitiveType(sf::Quads);
    m_vertices.resize(width * height * 4);

    // populate the vertex array, with one quad per tile
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
    {
        // current tile number
        int tileNumber = tiles[i + j * width];

        // find its position in the tileset texture
        int tu = tileNumber % (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);
        int tv = tileNumber / (m_tileset.getSize().x / tileSize.x);

        //std::cout << tu << " : " << tv << std::endl; <- Used this to out put it all, but it kept on showing the same coordinates and slowed the program down a lot.

        // current tile's quad
        sf::Vertex* quad = &m_vertices[(i + j * width) * 4];

        // 4 corners
        quad[0].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
        quad[1].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, j * tileSize.y);
        quad[2].position = sf::Vector2f((i + 1) * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);
        quad[3].position = sf::Vector2f(i * tileSize.x, (j + 1) * tileSize.y);

        // 4 coordinates
        quad[0].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
        quad[1].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, tv * tileSize.y);
        quad[2].texCoords = sf::Vector2f((tu + 1) * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
        quad[3].texCoords = sf::Vector2f(tu * tileSize.x, (tv + 1) * tileSize.y);
    }

    return true;
}
```

private:

```
virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    // apply the transform
    states.transform *= getTransform();

    // apply the tileset texture
    states.texture = &m_tileset;

    // draw the vertex array
    target.draw(m_vertices, states);
}
sf::VertexArray m_vertices;
sf::Texture m_tileset;
```

};

I've tried a few other ways to show them, but it all either doesn't do it correctly or slows the program down a whole lot. Can somebody point me in the right direction please?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Use a if statement to check the TU and TV integers, there your tile numbers, so check if those equal the tiles you are checking for the object to be on.

if (tu & tv == 1){ std::cout << "1" << std::endl;}